# arbitrary product of the closed unit interval is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

In showing that $\Pi_{\alpha \in A} [0,1]_\alpha$ is Hausdorff, is the proof pretty much the same as showing :

"$\Pi_\alpha X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff iff $X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff for each $\alpha \in A$ some arbitrary indexing set."

Or? You take two points and since they are distinct there exists an index element on which their component do not agree and everywhere else take the open sets to be everything? Does similar argument work here since $[0,1]$ is Hausdorff? (It is a subspace of a Hausdorff space, $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the product of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff: if $x \neq y$ are points in $X:= \prod_{i \in I} X_i$, then for some $i_0 \in I$ we have $x_{i_0} \neq y_{i_0}$; we can find disjoint open subsets $U$ and $V$ in $X_{i_0}$ (which is Hausdorff) such that $x_{i_0} \in U, y_{i_0} \in V$ and note that $\pi_{i_0}^{-1}[U]$ and $\pi_{i_0}^{-1}[V]$ are (sub)basic open sets in $X$ that are still disjoint and contain $x$, and $y$ respectively.